# Move SharePoint List with forms and Workflows to another site in O365

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, designer-workflow, list-form

I have created and developed a list along with 2 custom forms and a few SPD workflows in O365 site. I want to move these changes to the production site.What is the best and recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To Move a list with its related workflow in SharePoint online, you should try one of the below options:

1. Using a 3rd party tool like `ShareGate`, `Metalogix` or [HarePoint](http://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePoint-Content-Workflow-Migrator/Default.aspx)
2. Using `Save list as template` and `Save Workflow as Template`
3. Recreating the workflows manually by

   - Opening the SharePoint designer in both source and destination site
   - Create your list workflow, In source workflow `Select All` Steps and move it to the destination workflow.

---

**Save Workflow as a template Steps**

- Open SharePoint Designer, Open Your site.
- Connect to your SharePoint online account.
- Go to Workflow > click on your workflow that you need to move.
- From the above ribbon click on `Save as Template`

[image]

- The template should be saved to the **Site Assets** library.
- Now you have a template from a workflow.

**To restore from Save As Template**

- Go to Site Asset library.

[image]

- Click Export File.

[image]

- Go to your destination site > Click Site Actions and select Site Settings. > In the Web Design Galleries section >  click Solutions.
- Upload your exported WSP file > Activate it.
- Go back to Site Actions group, click Manage site features. > activate its feature.

[image]

For more details check [Ref](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wkng/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow/)